# When to Encapsulate in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have been developing websites using jQuery for 3 years now and I've recently gained interest in OOP in Javascript and I'm still starting to get my hands on OOP.

I read from this [article](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/), and it says:

> Encapsulation ...(its methods and properties) are hidden from the rest of the application.

but why would you wanna take the extra time to do that? When you are the programmer and you know you aren't gonna use that on another object anyway. Am I missing something imoportant here? I don't really see any need to do this on my current experiences.
So when exactly to Encapsulate in Javascript?

Comment: Haha Sorry @JaromandaX I just wanted to know if I was missing something important that makes people appreciate this. :D

Comment: `When you are the programmer and you know you aren't gonna use that on another object anyway` only if you are working on it alone and have the super memory to remember what-to-use and what-not-to-use years from the start of the project.

Comment: To those voting for close? How on earth is this opinion based? I'm pretty sure there is a solid answer for this one, else, why was encapsulation created?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I see your point gurv. and that actually is strong one to consider. It saves you documenting everything you did and reading it again, when the program itself has set the rules :) Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you are the programmer and you know you aren't gonna use that on
>   another object anyway

Only if

- You are working on it **alone**
- And have the super **memory** to remember what-to-use and what-not-to-use years from the start of the project.

As you mentioned yourself, it will help you in saving a lot of documenation effort in terms of *which-variable-not-to-use* and *which-variable-to-use*.

Comment: Thanks Guvinder!
Your comment was a good answer anyway! Just wanted to ask you. Do you enforce this yourself?

Comment: @JomarSevillejo ` Do you enforce this yourself?` Yes. `How?` That vary from usecase to usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

> In computer science, information hiding is the principle of
>   segregation of the design decisions in a computer program that are
>   most likely to change, thus **protecting other parts of the program from
>   extensive modification if the design decision is changed**. The
>   protection involves providing a stable interface which protects the
>   remainder of the program from the implementation (the details that are
>   most likely to change).

from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding

Comment: Can you provide a sample project situation where "the design decision is changed" is changed Savaratkar?

Comment: I will give a shot, not sure if it would satisfy your question. Say you are created a javascript plugin which is being used in many projects. You do not want certain part of the code touched in your plugin by any user. If you make it available/open, users might exploit it as per their need, which can lead to unstable state and your plugin actually will not serve the purpose. Information hiding also mean what information is allowed and open to use for an object. Kind of self-instructing guide to use an object. Hope it helps.